# MediaPlayer for streaming with cache

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, media-player

I want to build an app which will allow to view online video and to cache it.

But I need help with this: when user hits the magic "Play" button I want to start downloading video on external storage and to play it at the same time. How do I manage the whole process? What callbacks of `MediaPlayer` should I use? Any hints?

Comment: @joeyrohan I guess YouTube

Comment: Ahh! then same pinch.I Have you heard of [YouTube API for Java](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java)? Its cool,presently i am using it to search youtube videos.Any guidance needed for the setup?

Comment: @joeyrohan yes, I've heard about it. But I want a more general solution, so that I can work with other sources. My main concern is how to handle caching of video with MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking my projects:

1. https://github.com/master255/ImmortalPlayer One thread to read, send and save to cache data. Most simplest way and most fastest work. Complex logic - best way!
2. https://github.com/master255/VideoViewCache Simple Videoview with cache. Two threads for play and save data. Bad logic, but if you need then use this.